# Error on QT5.5 camera preview

Tags: c++, qt, camera, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to use a camera in my QT5.5 application using the `QCamera` type of QT. A simple example of what I'm doing is

```
QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::avalilableCameras();
qdebug() << cameras.length();
const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo = cameras.first();
QCamera *camera = new QCamera( cameraInfo );
```

When I run this example, I get "No m_videoSink available!" on the command line. QT is build on Ubuntu 12.04 with libgstreamer0.10-0, libgstreamer0.10-dev and libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 installed. QT is built with `-qt-xcb`. I have no idea what is wrong here. Does anyone have an idea?

PS: Of course I make sure that line 2 prints >= 1 ;).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I found the basic problem: Unfortunately Qt dropped Ubuntu 12.04 LTS support with version 5.5. With version 5.4 everything works as expected.